# Comparing text against list for multiple files using function and for loops

Tags: python, pandas, apply

My ultimate objective is to create a for loop that goes over multiple files with an additional for loop that compares an index of terms against the data frame. To make this more fun, I'm also including a function, since I'll likely have to apply the same principle to another variable in the same data frame. There are a few problems.

1. I'm not sure if I should be using regex in this case or if a simple `in` statement is sufficient.
2. The method I'm using is not efficient (not to mention it doesn't work). I was hoping that there is something like the `isin` statement, but each word in the list needs to be checked against one line of the data frame.  However, I'm not sure how to apply it when I'm trying to do something like this...

```
df:    
     'headline'                                                'source'
     targets is making better stars in the bucks               target news
     more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings                  wishful thinking
     diamond in the rough employees take too many naps         refresh sleep

data:
      'company'
      targets 
      stars in the bucks
      wallymarty
      velocity global
      diamond in the rough

ccompanies = data['company'].tolist() #convert into list 
def find(x): #function to compare df['headline'] against list of companies
    result = []
    companies = set(ccompanies) #edit based on comment, saves time
    for i in companies:
        if i in x:
            result.append(x)
    return result

matches = df['headline'].apply(find)
```

The desired output would be a list of headlines that match the company:
   
    `targets is making better stars in the bucks 
    diamond in the rough employees take too many naps`

EDIT: My script has been edited so now it works and shows the headlines. However, instead of just the desired output, the output shows all of the rows of the data frame with only applicable rows populated.

Comment: Those are lists, not dataframes?

Comment: It would be best to show the actual dataframe. Are you trying to compare the `headline` dataframe against a _list_ company?

Comment: Ok, I'll make that edit...but yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The headline in the dataframe should be checked against the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... should be using regex in this case or if a simple in statement is sufficient?

Using `in` is just fine, since you have apparently normalized to `.lower()` and have removed punctuation.

You really should try to use more meaningful identifiers. For example, rather than `i`, the usual idiom would be `for company in companies:`.

You figured out how to use `.tolist()`, that's good. But you really want to create a `set` rather than a `list`, to support an efficient `in` test. It's the difference between a O(1) hashed lookup versus a nested loop for linear scan of list.

This make little sense:

```
        for i in ccompanies:
            i = [x]
```

You start out iterating, but then `i` becomes essentially a constant? It's not clear what you were going for, there.

If you take this project a bit further, you might consider matching companies with NLTK
or TfidfVectorizer from scikit-learn,
or https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Comment: Thanks for your answer - [tag:set] made the for loop run significantly faster . How do you recommend I fix the for loop to make it work? For some reason, it's not working even without that line...python brings in the whole list of all ccompanies for each row  in  the df dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Pandas without iterating and converting to a list.

First, join the `data` to the `df` such that the headline is "replicated" per company name being compared with. A temporary column 'key' is used to facilitate this join.

```
In [60]: data_df = data.to_frame()

In [61]: data_df['key'] = 1

In [63]: df['key'] = 1

In [65]: merged = pd.merge(df, data_df, how='outer', on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
```

`merged` will look like this. As you can see, depending on the size of `data`, you might get a huge DataFrame with this method.

```
In [66]: merged
Out[66]:
                                             headline            source               company
0         targets is making better stars in the bucks       target news               targets
1         targets is making better stars in the bucks       target news    stars in the bucks
2         targets is making better stars in the bucks       target news            wallymarty
3         targets is making better stars in the bucks       target news       velocity global
4         targets is making better stars in the bucks       target news  diamond in the rough
5            more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings  wishful thinking               targets
6            more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings  wishful thinking    stars in the bucks
7            more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings  wishful thinking            wallymarty
8            more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings  wishful thinking       velocity global
9            more diamonds than rocks in saturn rings  wishful thinking  diamond in the rough
10  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps     refresh sleep               targets
11  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps     refresh sleep    stars in the bucks
12  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps     refresh sleep            wallymarty
13  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps     refresh sleep       velocity global
14  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps     refresh sleep  diamond in the rough
```

Then look for the text in the headline. If found, puts a True in the new "found" column, otherwise, False.

```
In [67]: merged['found'] = merged.apply(lambda x: x['company'] in x['headline'], axis=1)
```

Then remove headlines where no match was found:

```
In [68]: found_df = merged.drop(merged[merged['found']==False].index)

In [69]: found_df
Out[69]:
                                             headline         source               company  found
0         targets is making better stars in the bucks    target news               targets   True
1         targets is making better stars in the bucks    target news    stars in the bucks   True
14  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps  refresh sleep  diamond in the rough   True
```

If necessary, summarize to headline and company only

```
In [70]: found_df[['headline', 'company']]
Out[70]:
                                             headline               company
0         targets is making better stars in the bucks               targets
1         targets is making better stars in the bucks    stars in the bucks
14  diamond in the rough employees take too many naps  diamond in the rough
```

**Shortcut**: Steps 67 until the end can be summarized with this command

```
merged.drop(merged[merged.apply(lambda x: x['company'] in x['headline'], axis=1) == False].index)[['headline', 'source']]
```